# XDB Shard Databases in Azure Failover Group

Tags: xdb, xconnect, azure

Our client has a requirement for two copies of data.  Can the shard databases be in an Azure failover group?

First attempt, back up the original databases, then restore them to the primary and secondary SQL servers.  Then update the ShardsGlobal and ShardsLocal tables.  However, we are still seeing errors in xc-search, I suspect because of the process of how the databases were restored under a different name and in the failover group.

Would it be better to start over, run the shard scripts to properly initialize the databases with the right database names, then add those to the failover group?

Comment: why don't you consider sql replication in Azure?